# Proof about finite sets and bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I proved the easy direction: let B be a set of cardinality $n$ and assume there exists a bijection between B and A. We don't know anything about A but because there is a bijection between them, they must have the same cardinality. Since n is some number, A is finite.

The other direction is hard. Assume A is finite, so $|A|$ = $m$ for some m. I let B be some set of cardinality $m$.

I want to reason about functions between them, but it's a bit tricky. What if n > m or n < m?

Comment: If $n<m,n>m$, then $A$ is not bijective to $[n]$.

Comment: You should be using the definition of "finite" given in the first sentence of the problem, and not the intuitive definition "$|A|=m$ for some $m$."

Comment: @blf i will do that, thank you

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar it makes sense, so we have to disregard those.. but what does that mean about my set A here? I guess I should ask you what a properly contained subset is, and try to work with that

Comment: @furashu: Yes. Thanks.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar what are you thanking me for :P

also I guess he just meant proper subset, so the subset isnt empty and it's not the whole set. this can actually be helpful.. [n] is the set of all sets of cardinality n, correct?

Comment: @furashu: No, $[n]$ is the set of all natural numbers until the number $n$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar so by the definition of finite I cannot find a bijection to a subset of [n], I have to find one to [n], which is why we cannot have n < m or n > m ?

Comment: @furashu: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is bijective to $[n] := \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n$. Then any proper subset $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ will have cardinality $|\tilde{A}|= m$ for some $m<n$ (in other words, $\tilde{A}$ is bijective to $[m]$ with $m<n$). By the hint given at the end of the problem, no map from $[n]$ to $[m]$ is injective, so $[n]$ is not bijective to $[m]$. Hence, $A$ is not bijective with $\tilde{A}$, for any proper subset $\tilde{A}$. By definition, $A$ is finite.

I'll leave it to you to prove the other direction.

Comment: that is very helpful. it's clear that [n] is finite too by that hint, would the easiest way to do the other direction be to prove that they are both of cardinality n?

Comment: @furashu Yep, that's the contradiction.

Comment: well I wasn't aware it would be a contradiction, perhaps I am thinking of this in the wrong way.

Comment: @furashu There's multiple ways of writing the proof, so you might still be right. I thought of it this way: suppose $A$ is not finite, that is, it is bijective with a proper subset. If $A$ is bijective to $[n]$, then that means the proper subset is also bijective to $[n]$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: why does that mean the proper subset is also bijective to [n]?

Comment: @furashu We assumed that $A$ is bijective with the proper subset.